# Counting the files in a web service directory in Javascript \ Angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I'm primarily using Angular 2/4 for this but am completely unsure how to approach this.

The app I'd like to make is a quiz app. The quizzes are stored in individual JSON files. I would like a menu screen that lists all the quizzes. I would grab the Quiz.Title and the Quiz.Image from the JSON files but I would need it to loop until all quizzes are shown and so would need to be able dynamically calculate how many JSON files there are.

I would also like to know if there are any better approaches to create this kind of application.

Thanks

Comment: You'd need to provide/generate a list of these files as a Javascript on the client side can not access the server file system

Comment: Is there a way for me to do this server side and then pass the number client side? Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the technology your webserver provides

Comment: Ok -- so using a PHP file to collect the number, pass it through - would that be considered a reasonable approach for looping through x number of JSONs? Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely, but you should cache the result (DB, PHP Cache or filesystem)